# After converting to generic method, getall function is not working

Tags: java, mysql, rest, generics, crud

I Want to make a project to learn Java ee. I have planned to build a ticket management system. So i have created a mysql database, entity classes, access classes, ejb classes and finally WService classes. For individual Seat and Customer table my CRUD operation works ok. I have tasted with Soap UI.

After that i have made a generic access class. Now my get option is not working and i am getting

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

and from glassfish server log i have got the following reply.

> [2018-01-17T12:02:48.966+0100] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1516186968966] [levelValue: 1000] [[
>     MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json;charset=utf-8, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List.]]

From other 3 methods i am getting "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" reply.

Here is the sample code of access class, getall method

```
public <A extends EntityCode> List<A> getAll(Class<A> type) {

    final String method = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName(); // to take the method name
    LOGGER.entering(CLASS, method);

    List<A> result = null;
    try {           
        TypedQuery<A> holderQuery= em.createNamedQuery(type.getSimpleName() + ".findAll", type);
        result = holderQuery.getResultList();
        return result;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, String.format("Something Wrong..."), ex);
        return result;
    } finally {
        LOGGER.exiting(CLASS, method, result);
    }   
}
```

and here is code for getallseat from ejb class

```
public List<Seat> getAllSeat() {
    List<Seat> allSeatCaller = new ArrayList<>(accessObject.getAll(Seat.class));
    return allSeatCaller;
}
```

Here is the code from my webservice class

```
@GET
@Path("getAllSeats")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public Response getAllSeats() {
    List<Seat> variable = seatPrice.getAllSeat();
    GenericEntity<List<Seat>> genericList = new GenericEntity<List<Seat>>(variable) {};
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Response.Status.OK);
    builder.entity(genericList);
    Response response = builder.build();
    return response;
```

Before creating the generic access class all the CRUD methods were working well.

Answer (score 1):

Actually all the codes are fine. Probably there is a problem with dealing with server. I have created the JAVA_HOME and added on the path. Turn off the server Turn it on again and deploy the project again. And magically it works. If someone knows the explanation please share.

Comment: It may have been the case that without the JAVA_HOME variable being set it was using the default Java located on the path, which would be your JRE and not the JDK.